# Easiest way to move Google Photos from one account to another

Tags: gmail, google-photos

I have a work Gmail account that unfortunately has all my photos attached to it.

If I were to share the photos with my home Gmail account and the work account was deleted would my old photos go with it or would they persist?

If not, whats the easiest way to transfer the files from one Google account to another. It seems tedious to download 50GB and upload 50GB!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple.

1. Create a shared folder on your personal account with write permission.
2. Login to your work account
3. Click "shared with me"
4. Right click on the folder in you want to copy

[image: 4. Select the "shared folder"]

For future use, I suggest leaving the shared folder in place so you can just move the files you want there and then there automatically on your account.

I created a folder named "work" on my personal account and shared it with my work account.  This way the files in the "work" folder are always on your account, but still visible from work.  You can disconnect them at any time and not lose anything.